Highcharts Gantt fixed width of the left axis as a table column
I use Highcharts (Gantt module) to generate a Gantt Resources Management chart with a left axis as a table.
It works very well but, for a specific alignement reason with other charts, I need to fix the width of this left axis column (with a larger width than the longest label inside).
How can I achieve that ?
I tried a width: 250, setting in the Y-axis or in the gridColumns/label settings but it doesn't change anything.
An example of chart can be viewed here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/ryfmzxpe/3/
In this sample, I'de like the "resource" columns to have a fixed width of 250 pixels (for instance).

There is no direct way to set the column's width. Reported feature request: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20277
However, the width of the column is adjusted to its content, so you can increase an individual label's width. For example:
labels: {
  useHTML: true,
  formatter: function () {
    if (this.value === "Group A") {
      return `<div style="width: 250px;">${this.value}</div>`;
    }

    return this.value;
  }
}


Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z8kfb0p2/
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels
